# How to kill xkill?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I entered xkill command, then changed my mind and then pressed ctrl+z in linux terminal. How to stop xkill command now?

Do not read below. I dont understand what is wrong and why I need to write too much text. Without this paragraph stackoverflow deny this question.

Comment: Just Right Click the window instead of Left Click will cancel the Kill command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always bring a `Ctrl-Z`'d (backgrounded) process back into foreground using the `fg` command (eventually with the respective job ID, if needed), then you can use `Ctrl-C` as if `Ctrl-Z` never happened:

```
laptop:/home/me> xkill
Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1....
^Z
[1]  + 22082 Suspended                     xkill
laptop:/home/me> fg
xkill
^C
laptop:/home/me>
```

More details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/how-to-suspend-and-bring-a-background-process-to-foreground).

Answer (score 2):

I would try: `pkill -9 xkill` . This will kill with sigkill any process which greps for xkill.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the process ID of the command you just ran. run the command `ps -aux | grep xkill` to get the Process ID, and then run `kill -9 <Process ID>` and it should not be running any more. Just to make sure run again `ps -aux | grep xkill` to verify that its not there any more